# Oracle FORALL does not improve performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I am using oracle FORALL construct to improve performance of a PL/SQL block. I am writing down the 'before' and 'after' code of the FORALL -

**BEFORE:**

```
 FOR employee_rec IN (SELECT employee_id
                      FROM employees
                      WHERE department_id =
                      increase_salary_prc.p_department_id_in)
 LOOP
    check_eligibility_prc (employee_rec.employee_id, l_eligible);

    IF l_eligible THEN
      UPDATE employees emp
      SET emp.salary = emp.salary + emp.salary * increase_salary_prc.p_increase_pct_in
      WHERE emp.employee_id = employee_rec.employee_id;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

**AFTER:**

```
 TYPE employee_ids_t IS TABLE OF employees.employee_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 
 l_employee_ids   employee_ids_t;
 l_eligible_ids   employee_ids_t;

 BEGIN

 SELECT employee_id
 BULK COLLECT INTO l_employee_ids
 FROM employees
 WHERE department_id = increase_salary_prc.p_department_id_in;

 FOR indx IN 1..l_employee_ids.COUNT 
 LOOP
    check_eligibility_prc (l_employee_ids(indx),
                           l_eligible);

    IF l_eligible THEN
      l_eligible_ids(l_eligible_ids.COUNT + 1) := l_employee_ids(indx);
    END IF;  
 END LOOP;

 FORALL indx IN 1..l_eligible_ids.COUNT
      UPDATE employees emp
      SET emp.salary = emp.salary + emp.salary * increase_salary_prc.p_increase_pct_in
      WHERE emp.employee_id = l_eligible_ids(indx);
```

Additional Information -

Total employee records - 20000 
There are 2 departments - 15 and 16, each contains 10000 records. Procedure runs only for department 15. Among 10000, eligible for update is 5000.

code for check_eligibility_prc -

```
SELECT eligible
INTO l_eligible
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id;

IF l_eligible = 'Y' THEN
   p_eligible := TRUE;
ELSE
   p_eligible := FALSE;
END IF;
```

In 'before' code - 
1. for loop runs 10000 times
2. the 'IF' inside loop is true for 5000 times. So the update query runs 5000 times.

In 'after' code - 
1. For loop runs 10000 times.
2. the 'IF' inside loop is true for 5000 times. 
3. the l_eligible_ids insidd the FORALL loop contains 5000 records to be updated

With the 'before' block, the code took `637.42` sec to run. But astonishingly the 'after' code took a minuscule amount of extra time. It is taking `637.545` sec.

Can anyone please give any direction regarding why is this happening? The BULK COLLECT and FORALL is suppose to reduce the time taken. Instead it is increasing the time of execution of the block.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question.  How many employees are in the table?  How many times have you run each block?  What does `check_eligibility_prc` do?  If most of the time is spent in that, then introducing a `FORALL` in the code above will quite probably have very little effect.

Comment: How many employee records are there, and how many are updated? It looks like the (very) slow part is the `check_eligibility_prc` procedure, not the looping, so maybe you should look at what that is doing. (A 0.02% difference in execution time from a single run of each doesn't tell you the bulk version is really slower, other things like machine load could swamp that; but it's safe to say it's not significantly faster either... so you're trying to optimise the wrong part)

Comment: In 'before' code - 
1. for loop runs 10000 times
2. the 'IF' inside loop is true for 5000 times. So the update query runs 5000 times.

In 'after' code - 
1. For loop runs 10000 times.
2. the 'IF' inside loop is true for 5000 times. So the l_eligible_ids insidd the FORALL loop contains 5000 records to be updated

Comment: @NoobGeek - please add significant new information to the question as an edit, not as a comment. Have you verified those are the numbers it's actually touching, and that many records really are updated? Why are you doing this in in a PL/SQL loop at all though, why not just a simple update with a filter of `where eligible = 'Y'`? Even 5000 individual queries and updates shouldn't take 10 minutes though; presumably you're sure it's this section that's slow, not something else in the same procedure.

Comment: To verify the thing consuming time is not the procdure: Would you mind to run your "Before"-Version without the if-Part and measure the time for the looped execution of the procedure without any update?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table? A row-level before- or after-update trigger would fire for each updated row with both methods, so if there is one that could explain the similar timing, if it's doing something that takes a significant fraction of a second - maybe looking for related records on an unindexed table.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Actually I am testing the performance improvement that bulk collect and forall have to offer me. That's why this circuitous way of updating :)
I am sure about the numbers. The table has 20000. After department filtering the filtered amount is 10000. After 'eligible' filtering the number is 5000.

Comment: Well, a cursor FOR loop as used in the BEFORE code uses bulk collect under the covers, so not surprising there's little improvement there. And 5K updates may not be enough to show any improvement from the bulk update, especially if the update's WHERE clause specifies an unindexed column. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis : I removed the call to the check_eligible proc and just allowed to run the update in 'before' and 'after' codes for all the 10000 records. The 'before' code took 471.029s and 'after' code  took 456.037s. Is the meagre gain of 15s is what should be expected in this scenario? I have not done performance tuning before so I am not being able gauge if the time taken is OK or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update employees emp
set emp.salary = emp.salary + emp.salary * increase_salary_prc.p_increase_pct_in
where emp.department_id = increase_salary_prc.p_department_id_in
and emp.eligible = 'Y';
```

It looks like exactly the same but would be much faster.

P.S. Ten minutes is an incredible low speed for these values. Even if 10'000 unnecessary selects.